# Dynamically access object field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, pouchdb

I am refactoring Vuex and I have a common action such as:

```
 deleteFromList ({commit}, {list = '', type = '', listPlural = '', data = {}}) {
  db.rel.find(list, data).then(doc => {
    return db.rel.del(list, doc.rooms[0])
  })
}
```

If `list` is set to `room`, it returns a response `doc.rooms`. So an object containing a rooms array.

In this case `listPlural` param would be passed with a value of `rooms`.

How do I return `doc.rooms[0]` dynamically using `listPlural` param instead?

Something like `doc.listPlural[0]`, just to give an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could access the doc field using [brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) like :

```
 deleteFromList ({commit}, {list = '', type = '', listPlural = '', data = {}}) {
  db.rel.find(list, data).then(doc => {
   if(listPlural){// check if the listPlural is not empty
      return db.rel.del(list, doc[listPlural][0])
   }
  })
}
```